# I want to print out the last result done by the loop C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
  int i;
  int n=0;
  int F[10];
  F[0]=0;
  F[1]=1;
  cin>>n;

  for(i=2; i<n+1; ++i)
  {
    F[i]=(F[i-1])+F[i-2];
    cout <<F[i]<<endl;
  }

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

now this is a sort of a fibonacci number generator, but it outputs all previous numbers in the fibonacci series. I want it to print the last one. For example, if the input is 8, i want it to output "21" instead of 1 2 3 5 8 13 21.

Comment: Write `cout << F[i - 1];` out of the loop.

Comment: thank you so much i can now sleep in peace, i appreciate this so much!

Comment: BTW You'd better to add some check for the case `n > 9`.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int F[10];
    F[0] = 0;
    F[1] = 1;

    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        F[i] = F[i-1] + F[i-2];

    }

    std::cout << F[n] << std::endl;
    getch();
}
```

Since you already know the index of the last element (`n`), you can just print that after the loop.  I also did some other cleanup that didn't change the functionality of the program.

Note that the program originally and still assumes that `n` is less than 10.

Comment: Well, there's no need to store all the previous values if the goal is only to output the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Just store only 2 last values:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int F[2] = { 1, 1 };
   int n = 0;
   cin>>n;

   for(int i=2; i<n; ++i)
   {
       swap( F[0], F[1] );
       F[1] += F[0];
   }
   std::cout << F[1] << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```